# Day-O clock format in macOS menu bar

Tags: calendar, menu-bar

I am using [Day-O](https://shauninman.com/archive/2011/10/20/day_o_mac_menu_bar_clock) as the clock on the menu bar in place of the default clock. By default, Day-O is showing the display like below:

[image]

Can someone let me know if it is possible to change the format to something like `24 Jul Mon 1:52 PM`?

I know entering `dd MMM E h:mm a` in *Date & Time Format* under *Preferences* will make it look like `24 Jul Mon 1:52 PM`. What I am not sure is how can I remove the number 24 under box so that it looks exactly like the default macOS clock?

Comment: Can't you just simply remove `dd` from `dd MMM E h:mm a` ? Or if you are talking about removing `date 24 in a box` then you will have to get into app's resources. But why bother with app in this case at all...

Comment: I am asking about removing `date 24` from the box.

Comment: If you want it to look "exactly like the default macOS clock" as you ask at the end of your question, then use the default macOS clock...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to hide the date-in-the-box icon (circled below)…

[image: circled icon]

…then deselect (uncheck) Show Icon in Preferences:

[image: Day-O Preferences dialog]

Comment: My favorite menu bar calendar widget/app is Itsycal - https://www.mowglii.com/itsycal/